# TTF webfont to desktop-useable TTF

Tags: truetype, font-awesome

I'm using a CC-BY FontAwesome typeface for icons on my Twitter Bootstrap-driven website. Now I want to use it in an image editor for a prototype of another website. But it does not work. I cannot use its webfont-TTF with my image editing application. How can I convert it to a normal font?

Please dont give me links to free-/shareware closed-source utilites. I want to know, why does this happening and implement my own script which would "fix" this font.

Comment: For what it's worth (50 reputation!) I am finding it difficult to find/enter characters using the fontawesome font under OSX (10.7).  I installed it through fontbook, and wasn't able to find the extended symbols in the character viewer.

Answer (score 3):

FontAwesome should work out of the box. Heres how to use it:

1. [Download FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/). Then open `fonts/FontAwesome.otf` and install it (either with fontbook on osx or by adding it to your fonts folder on windows).
2. Use the [Cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) to actually use specific icons. Find the icon you want there, select the icon and copy it.
3. Switch to your image editor, create a text item, set the font to FontAwesome, and paste the symbol you copied.

Comment: You shouldn't link directly to versioned resources (as they become obsolete or are removed as they are very old). A link to the downloads page should be more appropriate.

Comment: This totally worked, but for whatever reason I can't start a new bounty to give you the reward. :/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about http://fontawesome.io/ .

If so *there is nothing wrong with the TTF version of this font* and no reason to convert it. I have tested the font on linux by dropping the .ttf file in /usr/share/fonts/ and it is useable in LibreOffice, Gimp and Terminal.

You problem is almost certainly one of:

- The process you used to install the font
- You aren't entering the correct Unicode characters or your image editor doesn't support Unicode.

However you failed to provide enough details. You haven't even defined what you mean by "it does not work". Please update your question with details like the process you used, a link to the actual font you downloaded and the operating system and image editor you're using.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still looking for a solution: the easy way is to convert the included SVG font to usable TrueType or OpenType, using e.g. FontForge or an online service.

AFAIK SVG fonts have no DRM flags, unlike TrueType.